# IndexOutOfBoundsException in Adapter.onBindViewHolder in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My RecyclerView's Adapter seems to be crashing, I have visited a few questions but I cannot seem to understand what is going on.
The questions I had visited mention that a list has been initialised again but I don't think I am initialising any list.

The link of the most relatable question:
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51787603/adapters-onbindview-gives-error-java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-index-0/51787705)

**Logcat**

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.android.predictious.ui.market.voucher.VoucherAdapter.onBindViewHolder(VoucherAdapter.java:61)
```

**VoucherAdapter.java**

```
public class VoucherAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VoucherAdapter.VoucherViewHolder> {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private final String TAG = "VoucherAdapter";
    private List<String> mTitle;

    public VoucherAdapter(Context context, List<String> mTitle) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mTitle = mTitle;
        Log.d(TAG, "Constructor");
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public VoucherAdapter.VoucherViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.voucher_card_view, parent, false);
        VoucherViewHolder viewHolder = new VoucherViewHolder(view);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder");
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VoucherAdapter.VoucherViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder");

        String title = mTitle.get(position);
        holder.voucherTitle.setText(title);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mTitle.size();
    }

    public void setTitle(List<String> Title) {
        this.mTitle = Title;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class VoucherViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView voucherTitle;

        public VoucherViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            Log.d(TAG, "ViewHolder Class");

            voucherTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.voucherTitleText);
        }
    }
}
```

**VoucherFragment.java**

```
 mViewModel.getmTitleLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<String> titleList) {
                mTitle.addAll(titleList);
                adapter.setTitle(mTitle);
                Log.d(TAG, "Data sent to Adapter");
            }
        });
```

**ViewModel.java**

```
public MutableLiveData<List<String>> getmTitleLiveData() {
        repository
                .getVoucherCol()
                .whereEqualTo("category", categoryTitle)
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    mTitleLiveData = null;
                    Log.d(TAG, "Could not receive TITLE data \n " + e);
                    return;
                }
                List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc: queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    if (doc.get("title") != null) {
                        titleList.add((String) doc.get("title"));
                    }
                }
                mTitleLiveData.postValue(titleList);
                Log.d(TAG, "Successfully retrieved TITLE data" + titleList);
            }
        });
        return mTitleLiveData;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VoucherAdapter.VoucherViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder");

        String title = mTitle.get(position);
        holder.voucherTitle.setText(title);
    }
```

yout `mTitle` is empty when you create your adapter, so that is way you get the exeption. You need to change it to this one:

```
if (mTitle.size()>0){
String title = mTitle.get(position);
            holder.voucherTitle.setText(title);
}
```

You suppose to add values to it not like you do here:

```
 public void setTitle(List<String> Title) {
        this.mTitle = Title;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I strongly recomend you to remove this setTitle method.
Pass this list via your adapter constructor. If you need to change this list - change it in your VoucherFragment. You can do it two ways - the way you did with little changes:

```
mViewModel.getmTitleLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<String> titleList) {
                mTitle.addAll(titleList);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged;
                Log.d(TAG, "Data sent to Adapter");
            }
        });
```

or another way:

```
mViewModel.getmTitleLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<String> titleList) {
                yourRecyclerView.setAdapter(new VoucherAdapter(getContext, titleList))
                Log.d(TAG, "Data sent to Adapter");
            }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I have multiple lists to be sent to the adapter, can you tell me, how am I supposed to pass the list, either via the constructor or any other way?

Comment: if you have to pass lists from different places in your code you can use addAll method to your mTitile variable in your VoucherFragment every time with adapter.notifyDataSetChanged goes next. Actually it would be better in this case to create private void  updateAdapter(List<String> titles) method and call it when you need